# Aircraft with air bags for seats

Tags: safety, seats

Are there any (passenger) aircraft models with airbags for seats?

I had never heard of it but was watching a film where a Virgin Atlantic engineer mentions it for their business class and premium economy seats in the Dreamliner ( circa 2015)

Wondering if this is true and which other aircraft have this feature. Is this a premium class perk? Or is there something about the business seats that demands airbags.

PS. Is it easily visible if a aircraft seat has air bag protection?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airplane_airbags

Comment: How much protection and in what situations would that really help during the crash itself and _not_ hinder the post-crash evacuation?

Answer (score 2):

I saw one on Cathay Pacific A330 for sure. Not sure about other airline or fleet. It is on economy class and easily visible. It is a large piece of equipment on seat belt and clearly label as such.